# SSRS: Month Date Expression in Header Text Box

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have the following Expression in the Header of a report and while the report is working fine, the expression returns #ERROR... 'Argument Month is not a valid value.'

```
= IIF
(
Month(Today) = 1,
"December, " & Year(Today) -1,
MonthName(Month(Today) -1) & ", " & Year(Today)
)
```

In January, I want the Text Box to display "December" & the Previous Year.
For all other months, I want to display the current Month Name and the current Year.

I would appreciate any help or pointers.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have worked harder before posting my question but it was urgent and I wasn't sure I'd be able to find an answer.
This is how I was able to solve the problem:

```
= IIF
(
Month(Today) = 1,
MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-1,Today))) & " " & Today.AddYears(-1).Year,
MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-1,Today))) & " " & Today.AddYears(0).Year
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were close, I think this should work

```
=IIF(Month(Today) = 1, "December, " & Year(Today) -1, MonthName(Month(Today)) & ", " &  Year(Today))
```